# Pulling out a full node with child nodes using XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm using XPath to select an section from an HTML page. However when I use XPath to extract the node, it *correctly* selects only the text *surrounding* the HTML tags and **not** the HTML tags themselves.

**Sample HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
      At first glance you may ask, &#8220;what <i>exactly</i>
      do you mean?&#8221; It means that we want to help <b>you</b> figure...
    </div>
</body>
```

**I have the following XPath**

```
/body/div
```

**I get the following**

`At first glance you may ask, &#8220;what  do you mean?&#8221; It means that we want to help  figure...`

**I want**

`At first glance you may ask, &#8220;what <i>exactly</i> do you mean?&#8221; It means that we want to help <b>you</b> figure...`

If you notice in the Sample HTML there is a `<i/>` and `<b />` HTML tags in the content. The words within those tags are "lost" when I extract the content.

I'm using SimpleXML in PHP if that makes a difference.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. With both echo $result (i.e. casting the simplexmlelement to string) and with ->asXML() I get the "inner" tags in the output. Can you provide actual test code?

Comment: Okay, so I was converting to HTML then loading that into SimpleXML... edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath is fine, though you can remove the final `/.` as that's redundant:

```
/atom/content
```

All of the HTML is inside of a `<![CDATA ]]>` section so in the XML DOM you actually only have text there. The `<i>` and `<b>` tags will not be parsed as tags but will just show up as text. Using a CDATA section is exactly the same as if your XML were written like this:

```
<atom>
    <content>
      At first glance you may ask, &amp;#8220;what &lt;i&gt;exactly&lt;/i&gt;
      do you mean?&amp;#8221; It means that we want to help &lt;b&gt;you&lt;/b&gt; figure...
    </content>
</atom>
```

So, it's whatever you're doing with the `<content>` element afterwards that's dropping those tags. Are you later parsing the text as HTML, or running it through a filter, or something like that?

Comment: Removed the trailing period... however the question has changed somewhat.

Comment: I don't think XPath is the problem, so can you post your PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML doesn't like text nodes so you'll have to use a custom solution instead.

You can use `asXML()` on each `div` element then remove the `div` tags, or you can convert the `div` elements to `DOMNode`s then loop over `$div->childNodes` and serialize each child. Note that your HTML entities will most likely be replaced by the actual characters if available.

Alternatively, you can take a look at the [SimpleDOM project](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/source/browse/trunk/SimpleDOM.php) and use its `innerHTML()` method.

```
$html = 
'<body>
    <div>
      At first glance you may ask, &#8220;what <i>exactly</i>
      do you mean?&#8221; It means that we want to help <b>you</b> figure...
    </div>
</body>';

$body = simpledom_load_string($html);

foreach ($body->xpath('/body/div') as $div)
{
    var_dump($div->innerHTML());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SimpleXML is different but to me it seems you need to make sure you're selecting all node types and not just text. In standard XPath you would do /body/div/node()